# How to lazyload JS script to improve site speed

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I want to install this script on my Ghost blog (it's a chat widget)

`

```
<!-- start Gist JS code-->
<script>
    (function(d,h,w){var gist=w.gist=w.gist||[];gist.methods=['trackPageView','identify','track','setAppId'];gist.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);gist.push(e);return gist;}};for(var i=0;i<gist.methods.length;i++){var c=gist.methods[i];gist[c]=gist.factory(c)}s=d.createElement('script'),s.src="https://widget.getgist.com",s.async=!0,e=d.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],e.appendChild(s),s.addEventListener('load',function(e){},!1),gist.setAppId("a2o4vdjf"),gist.trackPageView()})(document,'head',window);
</script>
<!-- end Gist JS code-->
```

`

But it's really slowing my site down. How can I lazy load this to improve site speed?

```
<!-- start Gist JS code-->
<script>
    (function(d,h,w){var gist=w.gist=w.gist||[];gist.methods=['trackPageView','identify','track','setAppId'];gist.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);gist.push(e);return gist;}};for(var i=0;i<gist.methods.length;i++){var c=gist.methods[i];gist[c]=gist.factory(c)}s=d.createElement('script'),s.src="https://widget.getgist.com",s.async=!0,e=d.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],e.appendChild(s),s.addEventListener('load',function(e){},!1),gist.setAppId("a2o4vdjf"),gist.trackPageView()})(document,'head',window);
</script>
<!-- end Gist JS code-->
```

Comment: If you can import that thing as a module, this API is pretty neat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library that supports lazy loading like LazyLoad.
Here's how you set it up:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazyhtml@1.2.3/dist/lazyhtml.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" debug></script>
    
    <div class="lazyhtml" data-lazyhtml>
      <script type="text/lazyhtml">
      <!--
      
    Your HTML, CSS or Adcodes here. (including wrapping <script>,<style> tags)
      
      -->
      </script>
    </div>
```